# Guardar varios registros a la vez a partir de un rango de fechas

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un formulario en el cual solicito 4 datos; Fecha inicio, fecha fin, nota y archivo adjunto. Lo que trato de hacer es que si la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin seleccionadas son diferentes me guarde un registro por cada fecha.
Ejemplo:
Fecha Inicio = 1-11-18
Fecha Fin = 8-11-18
Entre estas 2 fechas hay 8 días, tendría 8 registros en la base de datos con diferentes fechas pero la nota y el archivo adjunto serian los mismos

En mi base de datos tengo los campos (id,fecha,nota,archivo adjunto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes generar las fechas que están entre tu fecha de inicio y término, recorrerlas y hacer el insert en la bd, te dejo un ej.:

**PHP**

```
// tus datos de entrada
$start = '2018-11-01';
$end   = '2018-11-08';


// generas las fechas entre el periodo
$end = new DateTime($end); // éstas 2 lineas son necesarias para que DatePeriod incluya la ultima fecha
$end->modify('+ 1 day');

$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($start),
    new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

// recorres las fechas y haces tu insert
foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
    $date = $value->format('Y-m-d');

    // genera tu sql
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('$date', '..')";
    //echo $sql.'<br>';

    // ejecuta el sql (insert)...

}
```

**Ej. del sql generado:**

```
INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('2018-11-01', '..')
INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('2018-11-02', '..')
INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('2018-11-03', '..')
INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('2018-11-04', '..')
INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('2018-11-05', '..')
INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('2018-11-06', '..')
INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('2018-11-07', '..')
INSERT INTO tabla (`fecha`, `..`) VALUES ('2018-11-08', '..')
```

El código propuesto funciona si ambas fechas son iguales y también en caso de que no lo sean.

Link de la documentación oficial sobre el uso de DatePeriod: http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php

Comment: Después de casi 6 años, y esta respuesta es muy útil, lo que estaba buscando. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Voy asumir que estas trabajando en PHP

Para comparar fechas en PHP puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
$fecha_actual = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:00",time()));
$fecha_entrada = strtotime("19-11-2008 21:00:00");

if($fecha_actual > $fecha_entrada)
```

hay puedes por medio de un while o un for recorrer un ciclo y cada vez que recorras el ciclo le sumas un día

```
//sumo 1 día
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."+ 1 days")); 
//resto 1 día
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fecha_actual."- 1 days"));
```

y dentro del mismo ciclo puedes enviar a guardar, así puedes obtener lo que deseas.

Comment: no hay que asumir nada, en las etiquetas se lee `php` y `laravel`